# How to make this interface?

Tags: gui-construction, cdf-format, interactive, deployment, cdfplayer

I was recently watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ofoxOvjJ00) on the role of the Wolfram language on data science and engineering, and upon discussion of data manipulation, the following CDF was briefly shown (around 0:50 in the video)

[image]

I'm looking to build a similar looking CDF. However, I'm not quite sure where to begin, and whether I'm even able to do something like this without the Enterprise Edition of *Mathematica*. What suggestions do you have in order to build something like this? Do you know of similar examples that I could look at?

My main goals are the following:

1. Have an interactive panel (with multiple widgets)
2. Button section where I can run/stop a calculation/simulation based on the parameter values obtained from the widgets
3. An output panel.

I've been trying to do this with `Manipulate`, but being able to implement it into a CDF like this would be great.

Comment: You work hard. Or you pay a consultant ...

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html is a good starting point for visitors to this page.